# Version conflict when using the delete method of elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

So, we're using elasticsearch in our Django project, and we're using the elasticsearch-dsl python library.

We got the following error in production:

```
ConflictError(409, '{"took":7,"timed_out":false,"total":1,"deleted":0,"batches":1,"version_conflicts":1,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1.0,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[{"index":"events","type":"_doc","id":"KJ7SpWsBZnen1jNBRWWM","cause":{"type":"version_conflict_engine_exception","reason":"[KJ7SpWsBZnen1jNBRWWM]: version conflict, required seqNo [1418], primary term [1]. current document has seqNo [1419] and primary term [1]","index_uuid":"2-fSZILVQzuJE8KVmpLFXQ","shard":"0","index":"events"},"status":409}]}')
```

And with better formatting:

```
{
    "took": 7,
    "timed_out": false,
    "total": 1,
    "deleted": 0,
    "batches": 1,
    "version_conflicts": 1,
    "noops": 0,
    "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
    },
    "throttled_millis": 0,
    "requests_per_second": -1.0,
    "throttled_until_millis": 0,
    "failures": [
        {
            "index": "events",
            "type": "_doc",
            "id": "KJ7SpWsBZnen1jNBRWWM",
            "cause": {
                "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
                "reason": "[KJ7SpWsBZnen1jNBRWWM]: version conflict, required seqNo [1418], primary term [1]. current document has seqNo [1419] and primary term [1]",
                "index_uuid": "2-fSZILVQzuJE8KVmpLFXQ",
                "shard": "0",
                "index": "events"
            },
            "status": 409
        }
    ]
}
```

The code that produced the error was this call to the dsl `delete` method:

```
connections.create_connection(
    hosts=[settings.ELASTICSEARCH_HOST],
    timeout=20,
)
search = EventDocument.search()
# The query is made by the django model's id
search.query('match', id=self.id).delete()
```

And here's the definition of `EventDocument`:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import (
    Document,
    Integer,
)


class EventDocument(Document):
    id = Integer()
    # other fields
```

Our biggest issue right now is that we don't have access to the server, we got the error through an automated email we configured for errors. So I don't even know how to reproduce it.

Hope you can help, thanks.

Comment: Your answer wasn't useful, this was a question about a specific library that works with ES and you just copy pasted stuff from the official docs that I had already read at the time, you were just trying to get an easy accepted answer. I don't remember how I solved this, but it wasn't thanks to that answer.

Answer (score 4):

This error is happening due to the version conflict in your documents. From ES official docs

> Elasticsearch is distributed. When documents are created, updated, or
>   deleted, the new version of the document has to be replicated to other
>   nodes in the cluster. Elasticsearch is also asynchronous and
>   concurrent, meaning that these replication requests are sent in
>   parallel, and may arrive at their destination out of sequence.
>   Elasticsearch needs a way of ensuring that an older version of a
>   document never overwrites a newer version.

Read more about how to handle the `version conflict http 409` exception in ES in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/optimistic-concurrency-control.html) official doc, which also explains why you get the exception and various ways on how to handle it and explains the concept in details.

Answer (score 0):

```
search.query('match', id=self.id).params(conflicts="proceed").delete()
```

Should do the trick.
Docs:
[elasticsearch-dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#extra-properties-and-parameters), [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-api-query-params)